# Family tree in Prolog

Tags: prolog, family-tree

When I try to see who is brother to who and same for sister it gives me the sons and daughter, I cannot find the mistake...

```
    father(pedro-i,fernando-i).
    father(pedro-i,beatriz(1347)).
    father(pedro-i,joão(1349)).
    father(pedro-i,dinis(1354)).
    father(pedro-i,joão_grão_mestre_da_ordem_de_avis).
    mother(constança(1320),luis).
    mother(constança(1320),maria(1342)).
    mother(constança(1320),fernando-i).
    mother(inês_de_castro,beatriz(1347)).
```

Any other opinion I appreciate that

```
    ancestor(X,Y) :- mother(X,Y).
    ancestor(X,Y) :- father(X,Y).

    if_then_else(X,Y,male) :- father(X,Y).
    if_then_else(X,Y,female) :- mother(X,Y).

    son(X,Y) :- father(X,Y).
    sister(X,Y) :- ancestor(Z,Y),X\==Y,if_then_else(X,Y,female).
    brother(X,Y) :- ancestor(Z,Y),X\==Y,if_then_else(X,Y,male).
    descendent (X,Y) :- filho(X,Y). 
    descendent (X,Y) :- filho(X,Z),descendent (Z,Y).
    grandfather(X,Y) :- ancestor(X,Z),ancestor(Z,Y).
    grandmother(X,Y) :- ancestor(X,Z),ancestor(Z,Y).
    grandchildren(X,Y) :- ancestor(Z,X),ancestor(Y,Z).

    uncle(X,Y) :- brother(X,Z),ancestor(Z,Y).
```

Comment: What query do you enter? What results do you get? What results do you expect?

Comment: for example if I enter this query: 'brother(X,fernando-i).'

I get: 'X=pedro-i'

and I want to get:  
'
X=joão(1349).
X=dinis(1354).
X=joão_grão_mestre_da_ordem_de_avis)
'

only those who are male, if I ask sister only the females
@lurker

Comment: `s/pedro-i/pedro_i/g`

Comment: @false Did not understand what you were trying to say.

Comment: Don't use `-` directly in names as in `pedro-i`, instead, use `_`. And if you really insist on it, put the entire name in quotes like `'pedro-i'`

Comment: thanks, I will do it, I appreciate. @false

Answer (score 1):

Your clause `brother(X,Y) :- ancestor(Z,Y),X\==Y,if_then_else(X,Y,male).` requires Y to have an ancestor, but X also needs to have an ancestor -- the *same* ancestor:

```
brother(X,Y) :- ancestor(Z,Y),ancestor(Z,X), X\==Y,if_then_else(X,Y,male).
```

You also need to eliminate the requirement at the end that X be the father of Y.

```
brother(X,Y) :- ancestor(Z,Y),ancestor(Z,X), X\==Y,male(X).
```

`male` needs to depend simply on the individual (you don't need to be a father to be a male.)  `male (fernando-i).`, etc.